# Switch Statement in JAVA does not recognize blank spaces

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am trying to figure out why my switch statement does not recognize either a blank space or a "+" operator.

I am trying to go through a string/stream input.

I have a cursor which keeps track of where we are in the string/stream input. In the code below, the program will work as expected (going through numbers) until the cursor reaches a value of "2" which means the cursor is on a blank space inside of the string/stream input.

I have made a substring of the original string so I can use that for the switch to work with just one character.

As I said when the cursor hits 2, and the number "10" has been gone trough (the input is : "10 + 15 * (10 + 3 * 3 - 2)"), it gives me an error on the white space. So the cursor will not recognize the white space and will not advance to the "+" operator. It even tells me in the error that "Expected a valid token at position : 2".

The main:

```
import Class.Parser;
import Class.Lexer;
import Model.Token;

import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

          Lexer lexer = new Lexer("10 + 15 * (10 + 3 * 3 - 2)");
          List <Token> tokens = lexer.getTokens();
    }
}
```

The Lexer class:

```
package Class;
import Model.Spec;
import Model.Token;
import Model.TokenType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.ToIntFunction;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Lexer {
    private String _input;
    private int _cursor;

    public Lexer() {
        this._cursor = 0;
    }

    public Lexer(String _Input) {
        this._input = _Input;
        this._cursor = 0;
    }

    public List<Token> getTokens() throws Exception {
        List<Token> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
        if (this._cursor < this._input.length() != true) {
            return null;
        }
        String input = this._input.substring(this._cursor);
        while (this._cursor < this._input.length()) {
            switch (input) {
                case "":
                case "\n":
                case "\t":
                case "\s":
                    break;
                case "+":
                    tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.PLUS, "+"));
                    break;
                case "-":
                    tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.MINUS, "-"));
                    break;
                case "*":
                    tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.MULTIPLY, "*"));
                    break;
                case "/":
                    tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.DIVIDE, "/"));
                    break;
                case "(":
                    tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.HAAKJEOPEN, "("));
                    break;
                case ")":
                    tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.HAAKJESLUIT, ")"));
                    break;
                default:
                    if (Character.isDigit(this._input.charAt(this._cursor))) {
                        StringBuilder number = new StringBuilder();
                        while (this._cursor < this._input.length() && Character.isDigit(this._input.charAt(this._cursor))) {
                            number.append(this._input.charAt(this._cursor));
                            this._cursor++;
                        }
                        tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.NUMERICAL, number.toString()));
                        this._cursor--;
                    }
                    else {
                        throw new Exception("Expected a valid token at position:" + " " + this._cursor);
                    }
            }
            this._cursor++;
        }
        tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.EOF, "EOF"));
        return tokens;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!
If information is missing, let me know!

Comment: You never update `input` inside the loop, yet you `switch` over it in each iteration, that won't do what you want.

Comment: change first `case` in input to `case " "`

Comment: `this._input.substring(this._cursor);` - the substring method doesn't do what you think it does. That form of it gives you the string from `this._cursor` _until the very end of it_. You seem to want `.charAt()`, or possibly `this.substring(this._cursor, this._cursor + 1)`.

Comment: Given the problem is that simple, the underlying problem you're having is that you don't know how to debug. Fortunately, it's easy! Simply figure out what you think the code should be doing, and compare that to what it actually does. There where these 2 disagree - you found a bug! Keep going. Debuggers make this process easy, and you should learn how to use one. If you can't be bothered - there's always sprinking loads of `System.out` statements throughout the code.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Indeed updating the Input inside the loop works. The cursor is now at 2 and the substring (Input) is now "  + 15 * (10 + 3 * 3 - 2)" instead of "10 + 15 * (10 + 3 * 3 - 2)". However, the cursor is on position 2 like we know now , and thats the blank space. Unfortunately the blank space is still not recognized and the program will imediately skip too the 'else' statement wich gives an error : "Expected a valid token at position: 2"

Comment: @rzwitserloot Thank you for the reply! I have tried to debug using breakpoints wich helped me alot understanding what the program is actually doing vs what i am trying to do! Like i have replied to JoachimSauer, updating the "Input" substring inside of the while loop helped. But unfortunately the white space is still not recognized. Its unfortunate becouse i really think its something verry small wich i cannot comprehend right now.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Hey your reply is what solved my problem ! Wow i did not expect that to be honest but i decided to give it a try. Seems that using charAt() in this context is correct ! I will still need to do my research on why the substring did not work here. So i am eager to find out! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

So these are the changes which fixed the problem.
We are looking at the getTokens() method:

```
 public List<Token> getTokens() throws Exception {
        List<Token> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
        if (this._cursor < this._input.length() != true) {
            return null;
        }
        while (this._cursor < this._input.length()) {
            char input = this._input.charAt(this._cursor);
            switch (input) {
                case ' ':
                case '\n':
                case '\t':
                    break;
                case '+':
//                    token = new Token(TokenType.PLUS, input);
                    tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.PLUS, "+"));
                    break;
                case '-':
                    tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.MINUS, "-"));
                    break;
                case '*':
                    tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.MULTIPLY, "*"));
                    break;
                case '/':
                    tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.DIVIDE, "/"));
                    break;
                case '(':
                    tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.HAAKJEOPEN, "("));
                    break;
                case ')':
                    tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.HAAKJESLUIT, ")"));
                    break;
                default:
                    if (Character.isDigit(this._input.charAt(this._cursor))) {
                        StringBuilder number = new StringBuilder();
                        while (this._cursor < this._input.length() && Character.isDigit(this._input.charAt(this._cursor))) {
                            number.append(this._input.charAt(this._cursor));
                            this._cursor++;
                        }
                        tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.NUMERICAL, number.toString()));
                        this._cursor--;
                    }
                    else {
                        throw new Exception("Expected a valid token at position:" + " " + this._cursor);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            this._cursor++;
        }
        tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.EOF, "EOF"));
        return tokens;
    }
}
```

I placed the

```
String input = this._input.substring(this._cursor);
```

Inside of the first while() loop, and changed it to:

```
char input = this._input.charAt(this._cursor);
```